# Spring Boot REST path mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I'm just thinking, what is the best practice to create PATH mapping for rest service.
Let's say we have following paths:

```
/users POST
/users/1 PATCH, GET
/users/1/contacts GET, POST
/users/1/contacts/1 GET, PATCH
```

The question is - what is the best practice to create controllers.
For example we have UserController where we technically could put all these mappings. Or - we should create seperate controllers (UserController, 
ContactsController).
f.e UserController below, if we put everything under.

```
@RequestMapping("users")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser() {}

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser() {}

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {}

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}/contacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createContact() {}

    .....
}
```

And if we create separate controllers, how paths should be organized then?
Probably it's a silly question, but i will be glad, if someone could share experience.

Comment: I am a fan for separate controllers as they remove coupling between Users and Contacts (for example) - what if later you want to use Contacts in a separate context? (i.e. independent of the User they belong to)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets suggest that number of entities related to User will increase in future. So it obvious  that it is better to split it according to entities:

*UserController -> UserService -> UserRepository,*

*ContactController -> ContactService -> ContactRepository,*

*FriendshipController -> FriendshipService -> FriendshipRepository*

From my experience, User Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends AbstractController {

...

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") Optional<String> @RequestBody User user) {

...

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<?> listUsers(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") Optional<String> authToken) {
...
```

related to user scope Friendship controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
public class FriendshipController extends AbstractController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/friendship/code", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateCodeForUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

...

 @RequestMapping(value = "/friendship/code", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrieveCodeForUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

...
```

Not sure it is axiom, but help me organize my code.

Comment: I'd even suggest that the friendship controller's mapping should be `@RequestMapping("/user/{id}/friendship")` and then all the other mappings are simplified into `/code`

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan for separate controllers as they remove coupling between `Users` and `Contacts` (for example) - what if later you want to use `Contacts` in a separate context? (i.e. independent of the `User` they belong to)

If they are separated, the paths would look very similar to what you have:

**Users**

```
/users GET, POST
/users/{user-id} PATCH, GET
```

**Contacts**

```
/contacts GET, POST
/contacts/{contact-id} GET, PATCH
```

If there is a dependency between `Contacts` and `Users` (and in this case, it looks like there is one), you can have it like this:

```
/contacts/for-user/{user-id} GET, POST
/contacts/for-user/{user-id}/{contact-id} GET, PATCH
```

This allows you to add contacts to other things (not just users) and users to other contexts (regardless of their contacts)

For example, Users of a coffee maker

```
/coffee-maker/users GET
```

Or if the coffee maker fails, who do we contact for repair?

```
/coffee-maker/contacts GET
```

Probably a contact for a coffee maker repair is also a User (but they don't have to be)

One more thing, you can turn it around and say that a contact is for an appliance (i.e. a coffee maker)

```
  /contact/for-appliance/{appliance-id} GET
```

My point being that if you decouple the contacts from the users, you can assign contacts to other entities instead of forcing the relationship to be `User -> Contacts` - unless, of course, you don't want to decouple them because of business rules or some reason

***In any case, beware that there are many ways of doing the mapping***